# deleting duplicate valuesand storing the oldest date value using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I delete records from the following table:

so that the result is  as follows[image]:

[image].stack.imgur.com/BE87A.jpg

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: well i want to the earliest clockintime of each employee of each day(delete the record for reapeated empid and date with other clockintime rather than the earliest like of empid 16 ) for my project also i  am new to sql so

Comment: so i hav no idea about how to do this

Comment: There is possible that same `empid`, for same `date` can  have same `clockintime` ?

Comment: no it's not possible @OtoShavadze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This keeps only that records, which have lowest clockintime for `each employee of each day`.

Another records will removed (just for clarify, that you need **actually remove rows** and not only filter at `SELECT`).

So, if you need actually remove, then you can use this query:

```
delete your_table from your_table
inner join (
    select empid, `date`, min(clockintime) as minclockintime
    from your_table
    group by  empid, `date`
) sub
on your_table.empid = sub.empid and your_table.`date` = sub.`date` and your_table.clockintime > sub.minclockintime
```

Well, subquery gets lowest/min clockintime for each employee for each date.

Then from table deleted all rows, when employee and date match with subquery, but clockintime is higher, than that minimal time from subquery.

This means that for every employee and day, only rows with lowest/min clockintime 
 are remained, another rows deleted.

This is simply, just realize subquery result and then think about `on` clause, thats it.

Comment: @DrishMali - Added little explanation in answer, hope you understand.

Comment: so if i have  to  store only the  highest clockin then i use max functon and chnage sign to  < in on clause then right? Also thank you soo much  @Oto Shavadze

Comment: Can you look at this problem  also  
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44355065/finding-intersection-between-to-select-query-in-mysql

Comment: For that problem you have one comment  and I think you should follow that link.

Comment: Is this answer working for you? if yes, can you accept it ?